# AngularJS template is not rendered correctly in MSIE 10

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, templates, html-rendering

I'm trying to show a progressbar with a percentage value. The no angular version works in Chrome and IE. But the angular version works only in Chrome. In IE it is blank. You can test it with your IE browser. I've also tried to set `value` to `"50%"` and change html to `style="{{value}}"`. But still not work. Is there anything I have missed?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.value=50;
}]);
```

```html
<link href="//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  
  <p>Angular version</p>
<div class="progress" ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-dark-blue" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{value}}"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{value}}%;">
  </div>
</div>
  
  <p>No angular version</p>
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-dark-blue" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{value}}"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%;">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-style` directive to change style dynamically with proper scope binding.

Changed  `style="width:{{value}}%;"` to `ng-style="{width: value + '%'}"`

[**Working Plukr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQhVvrCRFI0GA0E2Zbhi?p=preview)

Tested on IE10 as well.

Hope this could help you. Thanks.